# Which background color to use for Android Market's no-alpha "Hi Resolution Application Icon"

Tags: android, google-play

Now the Android Market requires developers to upload a:

> Hi Resolution Application Icon, 512w x 512h, 24 bit PNG or JPEG (no alpha)

**Problem**: my application's icon is **not a square**, and because alpha is forbidden I will have to fill with some color like black. Or maybe white.

**Which color** should I choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the mail sent to Android developers, "the Android icon design guidelines located at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html apply."

So you can use a transparent background.

**Later edit**: Roman Nurik (Android developer advocate @ Google) said on Twitter that it's ok to use 32-bit PNG: http://twitter.com/romannurik/status/8375870980886528.

Comment: oh, I thought "no alpha" meant no transparency. Was I mistaken?

Comment: Usually, "alpha" means partial transparency.

Comment: I tried to upload a png with transparancy, but in the preview the transparancy is now black. Don't know if I should rely on this preview, but it makes me wonder...

Comment: The background shows grey on my partially transparent icon in Play Store (which is ugly) I will fill my background with white color. It'll be better.   @Peterdk